# IQueryable conditional include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

I have some classes:

```
public Department {
  public HashSet<Employee> Managers {get; set;}
  public HashSet<Employee> Workers {get; set;}
  public HashSet<Asset> Assets {get; set;}
}
```

I am using IQueryable to get a deparment collection:

```
IQueryable<Department> deparments = Context.Department.Where (
dept => dept.CompanyId = id)
.include (dept.Managers.Where (emp => emp.level == Position.Manager) as Managers)
.include (dept.Workers.Where (emp => emp.level == Position.Worker) as Workers)
.include (dept.Asset)
```

It gave errors when the query is executed. What is the right way to do this? Here is the error msg:

> "The Include property lambda expression 'dept => {from Employee emp in
>   dept.Employee where ([emp].Position == Position.Manager) select
>   [emp]}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access:
>   't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types,
>   specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g.
>   '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'.

For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393."

Comment: Can you provide the error perhaps?

Comment: The error is needed so we have an indicator as to what execution is happening.

Comment: Updated error msg.

Answer (score 1):

As your `Managers` and `Workers` properties are the direct children of `Department` class and you don't make reference of `Department` in `Employee` class so you can't use `Include()` for this purpose.

I think you should do this by using subqueries.

```
var query = (from d in Contex.Department
             where d.CompanyId == id
             select new Department{
                 Managers = d.Managers.where(m => m.level == Position.Manager),
                 Workers = d.Workers.where(w => w.level == Position.Worker),
                 Asset = d.Assets,
             });
```

Hopefully, it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Include doesn't filter any data. Ideally your code works